# MariaDB - Conjunction-Search in Many-to-Many

Tags: group-by, mariadb, many-to-many, having, intersect

I have problems to implement an "and-concatenated" search with many-to-many tables. I tried to present a simple example below. I use MariaDB.
I have a table with process. To the process a can assign persons and tags. There is a table for tags and a table for persons.
There a two many-to-many relationships: tags_to_processes and persons_to_processes.

1. example: Find all process with person 1 and person 2 and with tag 1 and 2. Result: process 1.
2. example: Find all process with person 1 and person 2 and with tag 2. Result: Process 1 and Process 2.

Thank you very much!

```
'processes' Table
+-----------+-------------------+
|process_id |process_name       |
+-----------+-------------------+
|1          |Process 1          |
|2          |Process 2          |
|3          |Process 3          |
+-----------+-------------------+

'persons' table
+----------+------------+
|person_id |person_name |
+----------+------------+
|1         |Person 1    |
|2         |Person 2    |
|3         |Person 3    |
|4         |Person 4    |  
|5         |Person 5    |
+----------+------------+

'tags' table
+----------+-----------+
|tag_id    |tag_name   |
+----------+-----------+
|1         |Tag 1      |
|2         |Tag 2      |
|3         |Tag 3      |
|4         |Tag 4      |
|5         |Tag 5      |
|6         |Tag 6      |
+----------+-----------+

'persons_to_processes' table
+----------+-----------+
|person_id |process_id |
+----------+-----------+
|1         |1          |
|2         |1          |
|3         |1          |
|4         |1          |
|5         |1          |
|1         |2          |
|2         |2          |
|4         |3          |
+----------+-----------+

'tags_to_processes' table
+----------+-----------+
|tag_id    |process_id |
+----------+-----------+
|1         |1          |
|2         |1          |
|3         |1          |
|6         |1          |
|2         |2          |
|2         |3          |
+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Is the column's `genre_name` name correct or it should be `person_name`?

Comment: @forpas Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, it should be `person_name`. I corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `persons_to_processes` to `persons`, filter the resuults for the persons that you want and use aggregation:

```
SELECT ptp.process_id
FROM persons_to_processes ptp INNER JOIN persons p
ON p.person_id = ptp.person_id
WHERE p.person_name IN ('Person 1', 'Person 2')
GROUP BY ptp.process_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- 2 persons
```

Similarly for the tables `tags_to_processes` and `tags`:

```
SELECT ttp.process_id
FROM tags_to_processes ttp INNER JOIN tags t
ON t.tag_id = ttp.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name IN ('Tag 1', 'Tag 2')
GROUP BY ttp.process_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- 2 tags
```

Finally, you can combine the 2 queries to get their common results with [`INTERSECT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/intersect/):

```
 WITH 
  cte1 AS (
    SELECT ptp.process_id
    FROM persons_to_processes ptp INNER JOIN persons p
    ON p.person_id = ptp.person_id
    WHERE p.person_name IN ('Person 1', 'Person 2')
    GROUP BY ptp.process_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- 2 persons  
  ),
  cte2 AS (
    SELECT ttp.process_id
    FROM tags_to_processes ttp INNER JOIN tags t
    ON t.tag_id = ttp.tag_id
    WHERE t.tag_name IN ('Tag 1', 'Tag 2')
    GROUP BY ttp.process_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- 2 tags  
  )
SELECT process_id FROM cte1
INTERSECT
SELECT process_id FROM cte2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=acca8d4c7c9a676b295f973afe70b6a4).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Later I will look into it in detail. One question now. Could you also put the where-condition into the ON condition of the join (because it is an inner join)? Would that be better/faster?

Comment: Is there any advantage of using "WITH" in the combination of the 2 queries over `(SELECT-STATEMENT 1) INTERSECT (SELECT-STATEMENT 2`?

Comment: @Phantom Yes, since it is an INNER join, the conditions of the WHERE clause can be placed in the ON clause, which, in theory, is processed before the WHERE clause, although the optimizer may decide differently. But, I prefer to separate join conditions and filtering conditions. Also, in this case the use of the ctes adds only to the readability and (if needed) to the reusability of the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for you additional explanations!